# SSL expiry information with java

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, ssl, servlets

I am writing a jsp-servlet app to manage ssl expiry, I found this class: https://gist.github.com/sureshpai/8c762603969e78dc2c68, but I can't get it working, how could I show the ssl info in a table?
Thank you

Comment: Hey, What do you really want to achieve? It would be better if you could give some example/expectation and errors/results you have tried so far.

Comment: I want to show a table with all the ssl certificates that I insert in a database, one of the column of the record must be the expiry so that I can notify when is about to expire.

Comment: In this case, who is managing those SSL Certificates. If you don't have access to an actual SSL Certificate, then you must have the website/domain name known and accessible from your backend server. If any of the condition is satisfied then probably I can help to extract the SSL Expiry date. If none of the conditions above you can satisfy then I'm sorry, maybe somebody else can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be,

1. Create a controller (if you are using spring MVC) or action class (in case of struts MVC) which should prepare a list of VO object with required details (e.g cert name, expire date and etc...) (you could use the same code that you have shared in the post).
2. Set the VO (list of cert details) in the session like this `session.setAttribute("sslDetails",sslDetails);` sslDetails can be an arraylist or hashMap.
3. Get the attribute in JSP and iterate the collection.

Thats it. Hope it helps.. let me know if you have any questions.